# Is there any way we can connect "template arguments" of one template with "template arguments" of another template?

Tags: c++, templates

Is there any way we can re-use an template argument (like T) of one class template as a template argument of another one? 
Is there any way we can use "an already-defined class"  as an argument for a template? 
Considering the details in the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
/*QUESTION1: Can we use "a class template" 
as an argument for another template*/

//build class template C1
template <class T1, class T2> class C1{};
//try to connect C1 when bulding C2
template < class C1> class C2;  //how can we EXPLICITLY mean "C1" of the previous define?
            //side question: if we can do that, is that equivalent to: "template <class T1, class T2> C2; ??? 

//build class template C3
template < template<class, class> class T> class C3{};
//try to connect C3 when build C4
template < class C3> class C4; //how can we EXPLICITLY mean "C3" of the previous define?
            //side question: if we can do that, is that equivalent to: template < template<class, class> class T > class C4; ???

/*QUESTION2: Can we re-use "one template argument" of 
one template with that of "another one"?*/

//build class template C5
template < template<class, class> class T> class C5{};
//try to RE-USE T when build C6
template < class T> class C6; //how can we EXPLICITLY mean "T" of the previous define?

int main(){
    std::cout << "A great civilization is not conquered from without, until it has destroyed itself from within"
              << "A great code is not stopped from without, until it has to crash itself from wihtin"
              <<"_______________________________________________________________________Rango";
}
```

Any answer to any question would be a great help :)

Comment: I have read it a few times, can't understand the question.

Comment: thanks @273. Let me edit it and make it more clear :)

Comment: Can you explain your real-world use case?

Comment: Thanks @JeJo , perhaps template < class T=C1> class C2 will help to solve question number one?

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit . I have yet to see any pratical use. I'm an architect of my own destruction :D

Comment: thank a lot @JeJo . that's so clear and clean. It must come from a very tiny and organized proprammer. :)

Comment: Did you try something like template <class C=C1<...>> class C2 {}

Comment: You could try a 'using C1Type = C1<atype,atype>'
and template <class C=C1Type> class C2 {}

Answer (score 1):

`template <class T1, class T2> class A1 {};` 
`using TypeA1 = A1 <int,int> ;`
`template <class T=TypeA1> class A2 {};`

It's not the same as  'template <class T1, class T2> A2;'
but you could reuse A1 types in A2's instantiation.

QUESTION2: Can we re-use "one template argument" of one template with that of "another one"?

`template <class T=TypeA1> class A2 {`
`public:`
`using TypeT = T;`
`};`

`template <class T1=A2<>::TypeT> class A3 {};`